# Rounding Corners of a ViewController, like Cash App

Tags: swift, uiview, uiviewcontroller

This is Square's Cash App: [image]

You might notice that all the corners are rounded. What would be the best way to achieve the same look?

This is my non-working code:

```
extension UIView{
    func makeCorner(withRadius radius: CGFloat) {
        self.layer.cornerRadius = radius
        self.layer.masksToBounds = true
        self.layer.isOpaque = false
    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    ViewController.view.makeCorner(withRadius: 20.0)
}
```

Unfortunately you can't call .view of a View Controller, so it's throwing an error.

Any ideas?

Comment: Change `ViewController.view` to just `view`. It's an instance property, not a class property.

Comment: Oh, that worked! Any idea how to do this for the splash screen?

Answer (score 0):

put it in viewDidLoad:

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

view.layer.cornerRadius = 10;
```